# On the decomposition of stochastic matrices as convex combinations of zero-one matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, convex-analysis

Let "stochastic" matrix be the matrix whose rows sum to one and deterministic matrix be a stochastic matrix whose all rows consist of a one and zero.

For example $\left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0      \end{array} \right] $ is a deterministic matrix.

I am trying to show that any stochastic matrix can be written as a convex combination of deterministic matrices.

Comment: You just UN-accepted the answer below. Any reason to this move?

Comment: ?? And... why do you want to delete the question?

Comment: This goes against the site policy, the idea being that the questions and answers you post are not yours once you posted them.

Comment: And may I ask: these deterministic matrices are *not* the same thing as permutation matrices, right? I ask this here because it might help clarify your question to anyone as dumb as me

Answer (score 10):

Constructive proof:

Consider some nonzero substochastic matrix $P$ with equal-row-sums. Call $P_{is(i)}$ one of the minimal nonzero entries of row $i$, and consider the deterministic matrix $D$ such that $D_{is(i)}=1$ for every $i$ and $D_{ij}=0$ otherwise. Finally, define $m(P)=\min\{P_{ij}\mid P_{ij}\ne0\}$.

Then $P-m(P)D$ is a substochastic matrix with equal-row-sums and with at least one more zero entry than $P$.

Starting from some stochastic matrix $P$ and iterating the step $P\mapsto P-m(P)D$ at most a finite number $N$ of times, one gets a sequence $(P_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant N}$ of substochastic matrices with equal-row-sums and a sequence $(D_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant N-1}$ of deterministic matrices such that $P_0=P$, $P_N=0$, and $P_{k+1}=P_k-m(P_k)D_k$ for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant N-1$.

This yields the decomposition of $P$ as a convex combination of deterministic matrices $$P=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}m(P_k)D_k.$$

*Example:* Consider the stochastic matrix $$P=\frac1{12}\begin{pmatrix}2&4&6\\ 2&2&8\\ 3&3&6\end{pmatrix},$$ then a sequence of reductions, showing the selected entries on $12\cdot P$ at each step, is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\underline 2&4&6\\ \underline2&2&8\\ \underline3&3&6\end{pmatrix}\ 
\begin{pmatrix}0&\underline4&6\\ 0&\underline2&8\\ \underline1&3&6\end{pmatrix}\ 
\begin{pmatrix}0&\underline3&6\\ 0&\underline1&8\\ 0&\underline3&6\end{pmatrix}\ 
\begin{pmatrix}0&\underline2&6\\ 0&0&\underline8\\ 0&\underline2&6\end{pmatrix}\ 
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\underline6\\ 0&0&\underline6\\ 0&0&\underline6\end{pmatrix}$$ wich yields the decomposition
$$P=\frac16\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}+
\frac1{12}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}+
\frac1{12}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}+
\frac16\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}+
\frac12\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: I can not see why $P-m(P)D$ has at least one more zero entry than $P$. This is clearly true for $P_D$. The minimal nonzero entry of row $i$, or $P_{is(i)}$, might not be equal to $m(P)$ and hence $(i, s(i))$ entry of matrix $P-m(P)D$ might not be zero. Could you please elaborate on this?

By the way, why $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}m(P_k)=1$?

Comment: Note that $P_{is(i)}=m(P)$ for at least one index $i$ hence at least one new entry $(i,s(i))$ is zero in the next matrix (actually one cycle adds exactly as many zeroes as there are indexes $i$ such that $P_{is(i)}=m(P)$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution and example you provided.
I still have a problem, why $m(P_k)$ sums to one? (This is needed for the definition of convex combination)

Comment: This is guaranteed by the fact that $P$ is this linear combination.

Comment: Did you miss something in your comment?

Comment: Not at all. To be more explicit, the sum of a given row of $P$ equals the sum of the coefficients $m(P_k)$ (since the sum of a given row of every deterministic matrix is $1$) hence you are done.

Comment: A very interesting construction, thanks a lot! I guess this construction also works for rectangular stochastic matrices, right? Could you maybe also point me to an academic paper where this method is described?

Comment: The constructive method by Did is essentially identical to the constructive proof of the Birkhoff-von Neumann theorem, asserting that every doubly stochastic matrix can be written as a convex combination of permutation matrices. The proof can be found in Chapter 2.1 of Nonnegative Matrices and Applications by R. B. Bapat and T. E. S. Raghavan.

Answer (score 3):

The proof for the assertion can be found in ["Markov Chains as Random Input Automata"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2311462) by A. S. Davis. It is an extension of the [Birkhoff-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff.E2.80.93von_Neumann_theorem). Did's answer is based on the constructive proof of this theorem.