# Constructing a new Markov chain from another Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, markov-chains, information-theory

I have a very simple problem, but it seems I have difficulty to prove it rigorously.

Suppose random variables $X, Y$ and $Z$ form the following Markov chain: $X\leftrightarrow Y\leftrightarrow Z$. My intuition says that if $W$ is another random variable independent of $X$ and $Z$, then the following 
$$X\leftrightarrow (Y, W)\leftrightarrow Z$$ also form a Markov chain.

Any simple proof or disproof for this statement?

I am thinking more in terms of information theory. In information theoretic context, the Markov chain   $X\leftrightarrow Y\leftrightarrow Z$ implies that $Z$ has no "information" about $X$ once you reveal $Y$. In other words, all the information about $X$ contained in $Z$ goes through $Y$. 
So, since $W$ is independent of $X$ and $Z$, once $Y$ and $W$ are revealed then $Z$ still carries no information about $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by $(Y,W)$? A Markov chain $\{ X_n, n\geq 0 \}$ takes values in a certain state space $S$. If $X, Y, Z, W \in S$, then $(Y,W) \in S^2$, so it is not clear how you want to set this up.

Comment: How does $X\leftrightarrow Y\leftrightarrow Z$ define the Markov Chain?

Comment: By Markov chain $X\leftrightarrow Y\leftrightarrow Z$, I mean $P(x, y, z)=P(x)P(y|x)P(z|y)$. So the Markov chain $X\leftrightarrow Y, W\leftrightarrow Z$  similarly implies $P(x, y, z, w)=P(x)P(y, w|x)P(z|y, w)$.

Comment: Still unclear (to me): Be careful. Possibly relevant example: Let $Y_1, Y_2 \dots$ be a symmetrical random walk on points $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ in a circle (0 adjacent to 4, mod 5 arith), 50-50 chance of going clockwise or counterclockwise at each step. Let $X=0$ if $Y=0$ and $X=1$ if $Y\ne 0.$ Then the Y-process is a MC, and X-process is not.

Comment: By the way, still decided to leave [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/896331) in disarray?

Comment: Apparently yes. So nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on $W$. For example if $W=f(Y)$, then you are right, however if W is independent of $Y$, then conditioning on $W$ can increase the conditional mutual information $I(X;Z|YW)$! For example if $W$ is $mod 2$ sum of $X,Z$ which is independent of $X,Z$ then $I(X;Z|Y)=0, I(X;Z|YW)=1$ which violates the desired Markov chain.

Comment: Why $I(X;Z|Y)=0$ in the example you provided? You have not defined $Y$.

Comment: It follows from assumption that $X-Y-Z$ make Markov chain. I have just defined some $W$ which is independent of $X$ and $Y$ (again by your assumption) in such a way that Markov chain $X-(Y,W)-Z$ does not hold.